# Formulae Translation issues (#NAME?) Multiple languages users

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've been having some issues with some of my corporation workbooks. Here is the scenario, we have multiple people that use the same workbook however they are from different countries so some of them use the regional settings as PT-BR , others as EN-US.

Excel auto translates the formulae based on the regional settings, however if someone opens the file using EN-US as its regional setting, make some changes and then save it, when a person using PT-BR opens the same file, some of the formulae do not translate correctly so I end up with a lot of "#NAME?" errors.

Checking out which ones, they seem to happen at random but some examples are IFs (MAXIF, SUMIF, etc) some date functions (EOMONTH for instance).

Has anyone else faced this isse and how to solve this? I've found a post somewhere else from 2017 of a german user which a similar issue but there wasn't a solution.

Is there a way to lock the formulae language ?

Comment: Please provide **specific** examples.

Comment: (not really a solution, more like an alternative way to work.) Try to work on the same file via office 356 online, but choose open in app (instead of opening in web) to sustain the desktop-based work environment.

Comment: @p._phidot_ thats a  nice workaround, however my company uses g drive for business as its main repository so users would have some issues switching between a local file and excel online all the time.

About more specifid examples, as stated MAXIF, EOMONTH are some functions that usually break. But it seemly  happens at random I am trying to willingly replicate the behaviour by switching my excel languages back and forth using those functions however I could not get it to happen at will. If I manage to replicate it Ill post here how to do it.